# The method is(int) is undefined

Tags: java, junit, assertthat

I imported using the following:

`import static org.junit.Assert.*;`

But on the following line:

`assertThat(0, is(1));`

I get `The method is(int) is undefined for the type AppTest`.

The name of this method is so common in the English language that I can not find where to import this.

So my question is, where can I import `is` (and `not`).

Comment: Why don't you use `assertEquals()`?

Comment: @shmosel Because assertThat(expected,someMatcher()) is most often more readable, and easier to tune to usecases, resulting in better error messages, too. Seriously: almost all the time, I find that *assertThat* **is** the only assert you ever need.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept, I assert that it is working for you now ;-)

Comment: You might be !wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
```

`is()` and many other great helpers are all [hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/) **[Matchers](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html)**. And of course, you need the corresponding dependencies defined somehow. It can get a bit tricky, as hamcrest has some core matchers, and also that matchers class with "all" matchers. But once you figured which one works best for you, you are set, and all fine.

Answer (score 1):

`org.assertj.core.api.Assertions` is widely provide for test case ....

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;

assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected);
assertThat(actual).isNotEqualTo(expected);
```

Comment: Have an upvote here, although this does *not* answer the question. And note: it introduces another dependency, so you should at least mention the need to "include" assertj within project setup then. And also not that assertj assertThat is not junit assertThat + hamcrest matcher!